# Load UIView from a Cocoa Touch Framework into an Xamarin.Forms iOS app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a UIView in a Cocoa Touch Framework and I want to be able to load it in a Xamarin.Forms iOS application.

The Xamarin.Forms project has a shared PCL between an Android and iOS app that contains the pages and ViewModels.

I can compile the following UIView into a framework and add it to a swift iOS app. I can successfully bind the HelloWorldView to a ViewController.

Any documentation or sample projects on how to accomplish this, if possible, would be gratefully appreciated.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
public class HelloWorldView : UIView {

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        sharedInitialization()
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        sharedInitialization()
    }

    override public func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        drawLayers()
    }


    fileprivate func sharedInitialization() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }

    fileprivate func drawLayers() {
        let sampleTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x:20, y:100, width:300.00, height:40.00))
        sampleTextField.placeholder = "Enter text here"
        sampleTextField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        sampleTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
        sampleTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
        sampleTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
        sampleTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
        sampleTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.whileEditing;
        sampleTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.center
        //sampleTextField.delegate = self

        //sampleTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line
        //sampleTextField.text = "myString"
        sampleTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.addSubview(sampleTextField)
    }

    //: API Properties
}
```

Comment: You should convert swift code into C# code, from your logic, it's not hard to convert them.

Comment: That was just a POC I was testing. There is another proprietary framework I will end up having to implement into my current project.

Comment: @SushiHangover I tried the objective-c example and I can get the view to load but I get an NSInvalidArgumentException "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error when clicking Done. Should I ask a new question or would you happen to know what I might be missing. I do have a version where I disabled bitcode in the Xcode library. [github project](https://github.com/kingbin/InfColorPickerSample)

Comment: @KinGBin I would ask another question stating your problem so it can be reviewed by everyone...